# Get mutually exclusive records: Grouped by tag cloud, even by shared association

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, data-structures, ipython

I've got a flat CSV file with data like this:

```
tag1,pageA
tag2,pageA
tag3,pageA
tag1,pageB
tag4,pageB
tag5,pageC
tag5,pageD
tag4,pageE
tag6,pageE
```

I'd like to somehow segment the `pages` in to mutually exclusive groups depending on all `tags` they share either directly or by association.

In other words, the questions I'd like to answer are:

1. How many independent groups of pages do i have?  (Where independence is defined as sharing no common tags with some other group.)
2. For each group, what are the tags that define it?
3. For each group, what are the pages that it contains?

For instance, unless I'm miscounting, the above sample data has two groups:

```
Group 1:
(tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag6) ==>
  (pageA,pageB,pageE)

Group 2:
(tag5) ==>
  (pageC,pageD)
```

What would be a reasonable way to obtain these groupings?  I'm open to using Python, sqlite, or both.

Comment: I suggest making your sample data set consistent with your sample desired results.

Comment: @kjtl see update to question. I _think_ the sample data is correct.

Comment: What results would you expect if you add tag5,pageA to the dataset?

Comment: @kjtl If `tag5,pageA` got added to the dataset, then I'd expect it to collapse to a single group.

Comment: I suggest making a class which has a list of tags and a list of pages. Then have a list of instances and run a procedure through the list to see if one instance can be merged with another instance. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {}

def add2dic(tag, page):
    try:
        dic[tag].append(page)
    except KeyError:
        dic[tag] = [page]

add2dic('tag1','pageA')
add2dic('tag2','pageA')
add2dic('tag3','pageA')
add2dic('tag1','pageB')
add2dic('tag4','pageB')
add2dic('tag5','pageC')
add2dic('tag5','pageD')
add2dic('tag4','pageE')
add2dic('tag6','pageE')

def query(iterable):
    aset = set()
    for tag in iterable:
        for page in dic[tag]:
            aset.add(page)
    return sorted(list(aset))

print(query(['tag1','tag2','tag3','tag4','tag6']))
print(query(['tag5']))
```

['pageA', 'pageB', 'pageE']
['pageC', 'pageD']

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I've updated the question for clarity.